# How do you dynamically update your Android application?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development, but I am wondering how an android application like ESPN Scorecenter or maybe a news application dynamically updates without the user having to do this manually. Will changing/updating the apk file automatically change the user's android app or will they have to update the version?

Comment: This is a _very_ broad question... I recommend starting with the Developer's Guide on [Building Connectivity](http://developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html)

Answer (score 1):

Android uses a SynchAdapter framework but this is a bit tricky.  The SDK has examples on this.

You could simplify things by using an AsyncTask or IntentService triggered by the AlarmManager which are a well documented set of classes

Comment: updating APK files will auto update your users

Comment: means stupid touchscreen and large thumbs

Answer (score 1):

Using threads to execute downloads in a determined amount time, and when the new content is downloaded you can refresh views using notifydatasetchanged().

Comment: Google recommends AsynchTask over raw threading to avoid zombie threads. IntentService is even nicer. Good mention of dataset notify.

Comment: yes asynctask are better, but how would you execute an asynctask to download new images every 15 minutes?

Comment: intentservice is better for that